# Lambdas and delegate types in NUnit tests: compiler errors

Tags: c#, lambda, nunit

I'm writing some unit tests. Taken straight from NUnit's [documentation](http://www.nunit.com/index.php?p=throwsConstraint&r=2.6.3), I should be able to do something like this:

```cs
Assert.That( SomeMethod, Throws.ArgumentException );
```

In a test method, this won't compile:

```cs
Assert.That(()=>viewModel.SaveCommand_Exec(this, new ExecutedRoutedEventArgs()),
  Throws.Nothing);
// Compiler error:
// Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'bool'
// because it is not a delegate type
```

But this will:

```cs
ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e = new ExecutedRoutedEventArgs();
Assert.That(() => viewModel.SaveCommand_Exec(this, e), Throws.Nothing);
```

And so will this:

```cs
Assert.DoesNotThrow(()=>viewModel.SaveCommand_Exec(this,
  new ExecutedRoutedEventArgs()));
```

Obviously, I've got two workarounds, but I'm struggling a little bit to understand what's going on here. Why can I `new` up an `ExecutedRoutedEventArgs` in the lambda that creates one delegate parameter but not the other.

More intriguingly, what exactly is the difference in creating the `EventArgs` object outside the lambda, instead of inside it? I realise this creates a closure, but I don't understand how that changes the signature of the anonymous method.

I'm using VS2013, targetting .net 4.0

Comment: How is `Expect()` defined? Why are you using that instead of `Assert.That()` in your second example?

Comment: What version of .NET and NUnit are you using?  Looking at their release notes it seems like a similar-sounding bug was fixed in 2.5.1

Comment: @swick. Sorry - slip of the cut / paste. This is an NUnit short-cut that not everyone uses - I meant to edit it to `Asster.That()` It's exactly the same. I've changed it in the question

Comment: @D Stanley: .net 4.0 and NUnit 2.6.3 (the latest stable)

Comment: Thanks to other contributors, I now have four workarounds / working alternate versions but still no understanding of why the original version doesn't work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have NUnit to verify but it could be that you need to explicitly cast the Lambda to `Delegate` to force the proper overload resolution:

```
 Assert.That((Action)(()=>viewModel.SaveCommand_Exec(this, new ExecutedRoutedEventArgs())),
                Throws.Nothing);
```

Comment: Ah, that compiles! It doesn't explain (to me, at least) why the version with the closure works anyway and the version without requires this.

Comment: There must be a different overload that the compiler is trying to bind to for some reason.

Comment: I'm sure that's the reason, but now I'm fascinated to understand the mechanism behind it.

Comment: You might ask a new question showing which overload it is _trying_ to bind to and which one you _want_ it to bind to.

Comment: That's a good idea. I'll have a look at that (probably next week now). Thank you.

Comment: Hmm. Can't reproduce this in a new project by copying (what I think are) the relevant signatures from the NUnit source (for new question purposes). I might spend some more time on it later, but for now, I'm not. Thanks to all contributors - points here as it's the neatest workaround and the one I'm using.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have access to the exact classes you're using in your example, but the following very similar code compiles and runs fine for me in VS 2013 targeting .NET 4. Are you using NUnit 2.6.3? Also, you correctly identified the only difference between creating the `ExecutedRoutedEventArgs` instance outside the lambda as opposed to inside it: a closure.

```
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            var viewModel = new ViewModel();

            Assert.That(() => viewModel.SaveCommand_Exec(null, new ExecutedRoutedEventArgs()), Throws.Nothing);
        }
    }

    public class ViewModel
    {
        public bool SaveCommand_Exec(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public class ExecutedRoutedEventArgs
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, 2.6.3. Sorry, I should have mentioned that (I was trying to minimise the NUnit aspect of the question, as I see it more as a language question).

Comment: I updated the code sample to look as much like yours as possible. I still receive no compiler errors and the code executes properly. The only thing I can recommend is to be absolutely sure you're running the version of NUnit you think you are and that you're targeting .NET 4 properly.

Comment: The difference between yours and mine (and apparently the problem) is that I'd put 'this' in the delegate where you have `null`. Presumably `this` still points to something in a lambda expression, but regardless, I still don't see how the method signature is affected.

Comment: Yeah, that definitely won't affect the signature of the delegate being created. Try this and see what happens: `ActualValueDelegate<bool> d = () => viewModel.SaveCommand_Exec(null, new ExecutedRoutedEventArgs()); Assert.That(d, Throws.Nothing);` I used ReSharper to extract a variable.

Comment: Yes, that works too. I suppose it's similar to D Stanley's suggestion to force overload resolution with a cast to `Action`

Comment: Re my comment on `null` vs `this` - actually I was wrong: `null` works on your example over `this`, but that's hardly surprising, since it's in a static method. In my proper test class, neither compile. So you were, of course, correct to say it wouldn't affect the delegate signature.